# Submitting a form in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a regular POST form. I have 2 submit buttons, one is called 'Submit' and the other is 'Preview'.

What I want to be done is, when the submit button is clicked, I want the form to be submitted regularly in the same window. But when preview is clicked, I want the form's action URL to be changed, and for it to be opened in a new window. E.g:

```
$("#myForm").attr('action', 'http://new-url.com')
   .attr('target', '_BLANK');
$("#myForm").submit();
```

And right after the new popup window is opened, I want the old action/target attributes to be restored, so if the submit button is then clicked, it would be submitted to the regular url.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="this.action = 'http://old-url.com'; this.target = '_self';">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- This triggers the onsubmit that resets the action and target -->
<input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="this.form.action = 'http://new-url.com'; this.form.target = '_blank'; this.form.submit();"> <!-- calling submit() doesn't invoke onsubmit -->
```

Comment: Does this have to be done with plain javascript or can it be done via jquery like in my example?

Comment: Yep, it can be done via jquery. Accepting for giving me an idea.

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know jQuery, except as the script that's the largest percentage cause of slow script warnings on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to limit yourself to HTML5 browsers and specify formaction="http://new-url.com" formtarget="_blank" on the preview button.